# Linux (Fedora) folders disappear from 'ls -al' and 'nautilus' view, but I can 'cd' into them on the command line when i know the folder name

Tags: linux, filesystems, fedora

I am experiencing an issue with Fedora Linux where folders are disappearing from a specific directory, the folders are not shown when viewed with ‘nautilus’ or ‘ls -al’, but if I know the folder name, I can ‘cd’ into it.

e.g.

- I make a folder in the director called ‘a’
- refresh the directory and folder ‘a’ will not appear
- I can open a terminal in the directory and ‘cd’ into ‘a’

what can I do to fix this issue?
(I checked the file-system of the HDD with Disks and no errors were found)

Comment: Check file ownership and permissions of the problematic folder: https://www.makeuseof.com/linux-file-ownership-groups-guide/

Comment: What's the *path* of that directory *'a'*?

Comment: the permissions all look the same, i also attempted 'ls -al' as root and I still could not see them, but i can 'cd \x' into them.

Comment: the path is, DRIVE/folderA/folderB/

things under folderB will 'disappear', I look for them (e.g. 'ls -al', but I can 'cd into them when i know the folder name'), the issue seems to be contained to folderB at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Just spitballing, but the behaviour you describe sounds like, for the folder in which your user is creating the new folder, that your user has write permissions and execute permissions, but not read permissions. This would permit you to `mkdir a` (write), and to `cd a` (execute), but not to `ls -al` (read).

Some replication for example:

```
$ cd
$ mkdir temp
$ cd temp
$ ls -lah
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x  2 preston preston 4.0K Jul  8 21:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 35 preston preston 4.0K Jul  8 21:24 ..
$ sudo chown root:root .
$ sudo chmod 0703 .
$ sudo ls -la
total 8
drwx----wx  2 root    root    4096 Jul  8 21:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 35 preston preston 4096 Jul  8 21:24 ..
$ ls -la
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
$ mkdir testa
$ cd testa
$
```

Comment: the permissions all look the same, i also attempted 'ls -al' as root and I still could not see them, but i can 'cd \x' into them.

Comment: A couple possibilities: (1) file access control lists (FACLs) are active on the files in question. Running `getfacl` on the files can determine that. (2) the files in question are on FUSE mounts: https://serverfault.com/questions/12162/directory-that-a-user-can-read-but-root-cant . At this point, it would be very helpful to have output of your shell activity in your original question, similar to how I have it in my answer.